# How to make Chapter numbers to be in position of dropcap like in the Bible

Tags: paragraphs, number, drop-cap

How to make Chapter numbers to be in position of dropcap like in the Bible (see picture)?
And how can I avoid number '1' for first verse between Chapter number and first letter in first line?

[image: Chapter number in same line as text]

Answer (score 2):

With the package `lettrine`. Using `\section*` suppress the section numbers.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lettrine}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy text


\begin{document}
    
\chapter{The One}

\section*{First}
\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=0.1]{\thechapter}{} \kant[1]
\section*{Second} \kant[2]

\chapter{The Two}
\section*{First}
\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=0.1]{\thechapter}{} \kant[3]

\end{document}
```